# Find the nature of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!}{(n + 2)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I need to find whether the following series converges or diverges:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!}{(n + 2)!}$$

I've plotted the graph of this series using Desmos and it seems to converge. So I tried finding a series with bigger terms that converges but I couldn't find one… Can you help me, please?

Comment: Perhaps you could bound it by $e$ or $e-1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$
1 \le \frac{1}{{n!}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {k!}  = \frac{1}{{n!}}\left( {n! + \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} {k!} } \right) \le \frac{1}{{n!}}\left( {n! + (n - 1)(n - 1)!} \right) \le \frac{1}{{n!}}(n! + n!) = 2
$$
for all $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Gary if you think my answer is a copy of your one I can delete it. Regards

Comment: @user I have no problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k! \sim n!$ and therefore

$$\frac{1! + 2! + \cdots + n!}{(n + 2)!} \sim \frac{n!}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

therefore the given series converges by limit comparison test.

Refer to the related

- [How to approximate $\sum_{k=1}^n k!$ using Stirling's formula?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164479/505767)

Comment: In my opinion this adds nothing to Gary's answer. You know, you can post links as comments as well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen At first the aswer from Gary wasn’t completely clear to me. Then I’ve provided a link for an answer which I found more clear and I’ve elaborated that one with a conclusive argument which I think can be useful for a part that f users. Finally I can appreciate also Gary’s answe more indeed I’ve upvoted that and also his answer to the question I linked here. It is all useful material in my opinion.